# Dynamic Sql Pivot Two Columns of Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Dynamic Pivots Tables, I'm trying to get this table: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f1cf/47

To look something like this: (Some Columns removed for brevity, assume I can have one or more columns past "Chosen Council", this is the expected design only not the expected result)

Note that Zip codes can be null, can share Councils, and can repeat over the days

```
+============+=======+================+============================+====================================+=========================+=====================+
| Call Date  |  Zip  | Chosen Council | Early Childhood Group Care | Development / Developmental Delays | Caregiver Mental Health | Behavioral Concerns |
+============+=======+================+============================+====================================+=========================+=====================+
| 2018-05-01 | 85000 | Maricopa North | null                       | 1                                  | 2                       | null                |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-01 | 85001 | Maricopa North | 1                          | null                               | null                    | null                |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-01 | null  | null           | null                       | 2                                  | null                    | null                |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-02 | 85000 | Maricopa North | null                       | 1                                  | 1                       | 3                   |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-02 | 85003 | Phoenix South  | null                       | null                               | null                    | 2                   |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-02 | 85004 | Phoenix South  | 1                          | 2                                  | null                    | 2                   |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-05-02 | null  | null           | null                       | 1                                  | 1                       | null                |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

I've seen a number of questions regarding Pivot Tables, both hard coded and dynamic, and I'm still not grasping it.

Here, I was able to get a Dynamic Pivot Table for just the Call Topic Names and their Counts: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f1cf/39
But that is only a single row for everything, it also seems to be ignoring nulls.

Here I tried to expand on the above, and while it seems to be spacing out better, I haven't figured out how to attach my Call Date, Zip, or Chosen Council columns: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f1cf/37

Any ideas how I can do this?

---

*ASCII Table made with: Made with https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like below

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', _callTopics.' + QUOTENAME(Name)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      _callTopics.Name
    FROM CallTopics AS _callTopics
    INNER JOIN CallTopicsPerRegion AS _callTopicsPerRegion
        ON _callTopics.Name = _callTopicsPerRegion.CallTopicName
    GROUP BY _callTopics.Name
  ) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
  SELECT CallDate
  ,Zip
  ,ChosenCouncil, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
  FROM
  (
    SELECT _callTopics.Name, _callTopicsPerRegion.CallTopicCount,
    CallDate
  ,Zip
  ,ChosenCouncil
    FROM CallTopics AS _callTopics
    INNER JOIN CallTopicsPerRegion AS _callTopicsPerRegion
    ON _callTopics.Name = _callTopicsPerRegion.CallTopicName
  ) AS j
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM(CallTopicCount) FOR Name IN ('
    + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', _callTopics.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
    + ')
  ) AS _callTopics order by 1,2 ,3';
--PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Here's <kbd>**[fiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f1cf/52/0)**</kbd>

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Comparing my script to yours, it looks like I was just missing CallDetail, Zip, and ChosenCouncil in my SELECT statement before the `' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '`